# How to create an empty array of Double

Tags: vba, excel

I trying to create an empty/defined array of `Double` which would reflect as `Double(0, -1)`.

I'm able to create one for an array of `String`, `Variant` and `Byte`:

```vba
  Dim arr_variant() As Variant
  arr_variant = Array()        ' Variant(0 to -1) '

  Dim arr_string() As String
  arr_string = Split(Empty)    ' String(0 to -1) '

  Dim arr_byte() As Byte
  arr_byte = ""                ' Byte(0 to -1) '

  Dim arr_double() As Double
  arr_double = ???             ' Double(0 to -1) '
```

, but still haven't found a way for `Double`.

Maybe with `LSet` or with a native function?

Comment: I think the answer below is probably true, but if you really really want to dive into details, I suggest these two pages: http://bytecomb.com/vba-internals-array-variables-and-pointers-in-depth/ and http://bytecomb.com/vba-scalar-variables-and-pointers-in-depth/.

Comment: The relevant question to me would be *why*?

Comment: @Wolfie, are you really asking why I would need to create a zero length typed array? Well an array not defined doesn't work with `UBound`, `LBound` and `For Each`, but mainly because I need an huge array initialized with 0 that I can compute and filter and where the expected output can be zero items. I'm still amazed to see that it's not possible with `Redim arr(0, -1)` and that the language doesn't offer a simple way to do it.

Comment: Initialising it with 0 is doable though, and why can't you output 0 items in an untyped array? I was just curious because I can't think of a situation when a quick check for emptiness wouldn't belay any concerns...

Comment: option base 0 ? I'm not sure want you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the only way is to call a native function:

```vba
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SafeArrayRedim Lib "OleAut32" ( _
  ByVal arr As LongPtr, ByRef dims As Any) As Long


Public Sub RedimDouble(arr() As Double, ByVal count As Long)
  If count Then
    ReDim Preserve arr(0 To count - 1)
  Else
    ReDim arr(0 To 0)
    SafeArrayRedim Not Not arr, 0@
  End If
End Sub


Public Sub Usage()

  Dim arr_double() As Double
  RedimDouble arr_double, 0    ' Double(0 to -1) '

End Sub
```

Comment: `Not Not arr` returns 0 and the call to `SafeArrayRedim` does nothing

Answer (score 1):

I would go with - **not possible**.

Take a look at the following code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub TestMe()
    Dim arr                   'Line 1
    arr = Array(CDbl(0))      'Line 2
    arr = Array(Empty)        'Line 3
End Sub
```

- Line 1 - It takes a Variant array

[image]

- Line 2 - Makes it Double array

[image]

- Line 3 - When emptied, it is converted from double to Variant again.

[image]

Comment: That's rather presumptuous to state that it's not possible since it's technically possible with a safe array. If not with a VBA function, there should be a way with a native function like `RtlMoveMemory` or `SafeArrayRedim`. And how is your code relevant to the post? The array from your example is a Variant array of and not a Double array.